# TI-Basic Storing Formula In a List

Tags: list, function, ti-basic

I recently became aware of an odd behavior of TI-Basic that allows the  programmer to store a formula into a list variable. I've become quite familiar with TI-Basic over the years and have examined samples of code from sources such as [TI-Basic Developer Forum](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/forum:home), This [StackOverflow tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ti-basic/info) and a [Subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/TIBASICPrograms/) devoted to TI-Basic  without finding anything other than acknowledgement of its existence .

---

The syntax to create this behavior is simple:

```
<String>→<List>
```

where `<String>` represents any string , literal or variable. Experimentation has shown that this String must evaluate to a list. `<List>` represents a list variable. Using a list literal will result in `ERR:SYNTAX`.

To help with understanding what I am describing, here are some examples using actual code:

```
"X+2→L₁

"2L₁→L₂
```

Both example will run initially; however, if I try to access `L₁` in the first example, I get `ERR:DATA TYPE`. Accessing `L₂` will return two times the current value of `L₁`.

---

As this question has so far been a description of this behavior without a direct question, I will conclude by enumeration some specific questions that responses could answer.

1. Have I correctly stated the syntax of this behavior?
2. What are some possible use cases for this behavior?
3. Where can I find official documentation of this behavior?

These are just recommendations for what an answer could include. I will be happy to accept a well rounded and general analysis of this behavior.

Comment: Great question - this is really under-documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad to answer a question of yours :)

1. Pretty much. The list variables are most closely related *in this behavior* to graphing variables - function, polar, sequential, etc. in their ability to store the string. This makes it useful wherever [self-modifying code](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/selfmodify) can be applied.
2. Basically, there are two main uses - self-modifying code and optimization. You're referring mainly to the use as optimization, where you store a lengthy formula into a variable for quick reference. Lists must return a list when called, so that's why your first example `"X+2→L₁` fails but `"2L₁→L₂` successfully returns a list. For example, L1 can be used to store any equation that returns a list. If you wanted to get a list of 10 non-repeating numbers from 1-10, you would use `randIntNoRep(1,10)`, 7 bytes (or 6 when unclosed), wherever you needed it. However, doing `"randIntNoRep(1,10)->L1` allows you to call L1 anytime for a fresh call of the 10 random numbers. Note that when not in string format (e.g. `randIntNoRep(1,10)->L1`), it will work, but each call to L1 will return the same list of numbers, since it is statically stored. Additionally, if the equation doesn't return a list by default, you can always add a list bracket at the beginning, but since there is only one element it would be much smarter to use a function or sequence variable (my personal favorite is `u`). Another specific use of this functionality is in the [Number or String](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/number-or-string) routine, for detecting whether Ans is a number or a string.
3. I don't know anyplace where this is officially documented, since unfortunately I don't have the manual to reference. If you have any additional questions, I'd be happy to answer them for you.

Comment: Great Answer! I dug up [this 827 page manual](http://ef.engr.utk.edu/ef152-2014-08/ti/ti83p-manual.pdf) after some Googling. It's rather lengthy, So I'll post the section relevant to my question in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In response to third question listed in the original post,

> Where can I find official documentation of this behavior?

A PDF of a [827 page TI-83 manual](http://ef.engr.utk.edu/ef152-2014-08/ti/ti83p-manual.pdf) is available online from University of Tennessee's College of Engineering. This manual contains documentations of the vast majority of TI-Basic features, including the one described in the original post.

The section of the manual relevant to the question starts on page 296 and continues until page 299.

> ## Attaching Formulas to List Names
>
> ### Attaching a Formula to a List Name
>
> You can attach a formula to a list name so that each list element is a
>   result of the formula. When executed, the attached formula must
>   resolve to a list.
>
> When anything in the attached formula changes, the list to which the
>   formula is attached is updated automatically.
>
> - When you edit an element of a list that is referenced in the formula, the corresponding element in the list to which the formula is
>     attached is updated.
> - When you edit the formula itself, all elements in the list to which the formula is attached are updated.
>
> For example, the first screen below shows that elements are stored to
>   `L₃`, and the formula `L₃+10` is attached to the list name `ʟADD10` The
>   quotation marks designate the formula to be attached to `ʟADD10`.
>   Each element of `ʟADD10` is the sum of an element in `L₃` and 10.
>
> [image]
>
> The next screen shows another list, `L₄`. The elements of `L₄` are the
>   sum of the same formula that is attached to `L₃`. However, quotation
>   marks are not entered, so the formula is not attached to `L₄`.
>
> On the next line, `⁻6→L₃(1):L₃` changes the first element of `L₃` to
>   `⁻6`, and then redisplays `L₃`.
>
> [image]
>
> The last screen shows that editing `L₃` updated `ʟAdd10`, but did not
>   change `L₄`. This is because the formula `L₃+10` is attached to
>   `ʟADD10`, but it is not attached to `l4`
>
> [image]

The formatting of the manual did not agree with StackOverflow so, I had to take some liberties in reformatting it for this answer.

Comment: Nice find! Since I couldn't find this information on wikidot I'll definitely read through some more of the manual.